# Imap slow while reading email in sequence

Tags: python, email, imap

i have created a script that should read the email's inbox without time sleep or other delay, the problem is that sometimes it need up to 7 second to read the email other time just 1-2 seconds (this morning), initially it does not close the connection so i add imap.close() but it add another 2-3 seconds
i thought i could be my internet connection, so i use a vps, but still it need up to 7 seconds.

should i try with another email? im using gmail
or maybe because i have too many email?

*the delay is in:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
mail.login('email','pass)
mail.select('inbox')
```

EDIT: i have deleted almost all the email, since i just read to read always the last; still it need 7-8 seconds

EDIT 2:
i thought it was due to the login, (because i called it every time, my bad), so i made it run just at the beginning of the script; and now seems that delay it is in mail.fetch()

but i have just created an account with outlook, and with the same code it need like 0.5 seconds to read it

EDIT 3: (the day after) all seems to work well even on gmail, i think it could be that i opened too many connection without closing it, now i open just one connection just at the beginning of the script

EDIT 4: now both need at least 5 seconds, im done, ill do it in c#

Comment: Fetch more than one message at once!

Comment: i just read the last one!!

Comment: Building a connection and logging in takes time.  If you don't want to take that time, you need to maintain the connection.  Having a very large inbox will slow down as well as gmail has to calculate a bunch of metadata to send to you.

Comment: i have left just 3 email still need many seconds; but this morning did it in 1-2

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, the problem is that simply logging in and selecting inbox takes 7 seconds before any attempt to get mail?

Comment: i tough it was due to the login, (because i called it every time, my bad), so i made it run just at the beginning of the script; and now seems that delay it is in mail.fetch()

Comment: but i have just created an account with outlook, and with the same code it need like 0.5 seconds to read it